# vue-konva how save layer with image and line like jpg, png

Tags: vue.js, save-image, konva, vue-konva

have v-group with image and lines on layer,stage like this:

```
<button @click="export"></button>
<v-layer ref="layer">
<v-group>
<v-image :config="configBackground"></v-image>
<v-line
v-for="line in lines"
:key="line.id"
:config="{
stroke: 'red',
points: line.points,
}"
/>
</v-group>
</v-layer>
```

in my function i try get dataurl from stage to save img:

```
export(e) {
//console.log(e.target.getStage())
let dataURL = e.target.toDataURL()
console.log(dataURL)
// this.download(dataURL, "img.png")
},
```

If i click button, i get **e.target.toDataURL is not a function**

How can i get dataURL to save image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work for me

```
let stage = vm.$refs.stage.getNode()
let dataURL = stage.toDataURL()
```